# all black box repack stop working .. .net framework 4.5 issues

Tags: .net, installation, black-box-testing

I have a problem with setup of all games that have black box repack setup. When I try to open set up file it crashes after seconds of downloading in 0.6% or at another game at 3.5% all games didn`t complete first 10% and this message shows up:

black box setup has stop working
widows is checking for solution
I searched online for a solution but nothing. Everything says that the problem in .NET framework.

I tried to install dotnetfx45_full_setup that comes with the game. It keeps telling me this:

Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 is already a part of this operating system. You do not need to install the .NET Framework 4.5 redistributable.

Same or higher version of .NET Framework 4.5 has already been installed on this computer.

Or in another game that have dotNetFx45_Full_x86_x64_SlimSetup after extraction tells that: Microsoft .NET framework 4.5 is already a part of this operating system, but is currently turned off. To enable the .NET framework 4.5 use the Turn windows features on or off in control panel.

So I go to features and check the first two, then restarted the PC, but still the same error.

I tried to do manually by cmd with this path: DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3 /All /LimitAccess /Source:C:\sxs, but nothing happens, still have that annoying messsage.

I tried to update my Windows version it was stuck at 23 %.

I searched online and finally I updated the version but the problem still persists.

I also tried clean boot. I noticed when doing clean boot that some Windows services stopped and are not running. Is that usual or not? Specially ASP.NET service state?

I know that the problem in .NET framework 4.5.

Comment: Did you tried this?
http://anything7272.blogspot.com/2016/09/blackbox-has-stopped-working-fixing.html